# How to identify day change in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, datetime

I want know to how can I identifies if there is a date changes i.e. 23:59 to 00:00.
I am using a servlet. I can do it using a static String type variable and assign it to "`dd`" part of below returned date stamp and comparing it on every request with the current "`dd`" date stamp. If both "`dd`" part do not match then it will be sign of date change. Actually there is one `static int` type variable that I want to reset to `zero` which increment till the day change.

```
private static String getDate()
    {
        SimpleDateFormat customFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd-MM-yyyy");
        return customFormat.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
```

But how can I do it without comparing it, is there any better way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: What is the requirement?

Comment: @markusw My web application has int type counter which on 00:00 should reset to zero and till 23:59:59 it should increase by one on every request.

Comment: Put that counter to the and check at every request if the last counter was yesterday. If yes, create a new counter.